# Scheduler in springboot for huge data alternate of spring batch processing

Tags: java, spring-boot, batch-processing

I have to run a schduler(any schduled jobs) where i have to fetch 300,000-400,000 in average twice daily from database and apply business logics one by one where each process requests to thirdparty which takes 3-4 seconds to respond.
what are alternates of spring batch processing to process such huge data in efficient ways?

Note: fetched data are not static, data may vary everyday.

Comment: Why would there be an alternative? A scheduler is something different then processing with Spring Batch? You can use a scheduler to kickoff the batch job.

Comment: spring-batch-lightmin provides an admin console for spring-batch jobs and also includes a scheduler

Answer (score 0):

May be [`@Scheduled`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) annotation can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Spring Batch schedular. It execute spring batch jobs periodically on fixed schedule using some cron expression passed to Spring TaskScheduler

To configure, batch job scheduling is done in two steps:

Enable scheduling with @EnableScheduling annotation.
Create method annotated with @Scheduled and provide recurrence details using cron job. Add the job execution logic inside this method.

Here is the link of an example : https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/job-scheduler-example/